# Single post view for custom post type plugin

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I have created custom post type "opinion" Plugin. My codes are following:

```
function create_post_type_opinion() {
register_post_type('opinion', 
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Opinions'),
                    'singular_name' => __( 'Opinion'),
            'add_new' => __('Add New Opinion' ),
            'add_new_item' => __('Add New Opinion'),
            'edit' => __( 'Edit Opinion' ),
                'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Opinion' ),
                'new_item' => __( 'New Opinion' ),
                'view' => __( 'View Opinion' ),
                'view_item' => __( 'View Opinion' ),
                'search_items' => __( 'Search Opinions' ),
                'not_found' => __( 'No Opinions found' ),
                'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Opinions found in Trash' )
                    ),
    'public' => true,
    'menu_position' => 5,
    'menu_icon' => plugins_url( 'images/opinion-20x20.png', __FILE__ ),
    'rewrite' => array(
        'slug' => __('opinion')
    ), 
    'supports' => array( 'title','editor', 'excerpt', 'comments', 'revisions', 'thumbnail')));
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type_opinion' );
```

But am unable to preview my custom post. It's calling content of index.php. I have created single-opinion.php for in my theme folder. Still am not able to preview the content of my "opinion" post type (introduced via custom plugin code above).

Kindly some one help me out to resolve this issue.

Comment: Did you flush your permalinks under 'Settings > Permalinks' and then press 'Save Changes'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As its a plugin, need to use the function register_activation_hook:

```
function create_post_type_opinion(){
register_post_type('opinion', 
array(
    'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Opinions'),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Opinion'),
        'add_new' => __('Add New Opinion' ),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Opinion'),
        'edit' => __( 'Edit Opinion' ),
            'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Opinion' ),
            'new_item' => __( 'New Opinion' ),
            'view' => __( 'View Opinion' ),
            'view_item' => __( 'View Opinion' ),
            'search_items' => __( 'Search Opinions' ),
            'not_found' => __( 'No Opinions found' ),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Opinions found in Trash' )
                ),
'public' => true,
'menu_position' => 5,
'menu_icon' => plugins_url( 'images/opinion-20x20.png', __FILE__ ),
'rewrite' => array(
    'slug' => __('opinion')
), 
'supports' => array( 'title','editor', 'excerpt', 'comments', 'revisions', 'thumbnail')));
}
//runs only when the theme is set up
function custom_flush_rules(){
//defines the post type so the rules can be flushed.
create_post_type_opinion();

//and flush the rules.
flush_rewrite_rules();
}
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'custom_flush_rules');
add_action('init', 'create_post_type_opinion');
```

ucheng's suggestion is good for custom post type within theme.

Answer (score 0):

From WordPress [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/flush_rules):

> WordPress keeps a cache of all custom rewrite rules. Sometimes plugins
>   or themes make modifications to those rules, however WordPress will
>   not actually recognize the changes until the cache is regenerated.

Go to 'Settings->Permalinks' and check 'Post Name' as the site url structure and save the settings to flush the rewrite rules.

If the method above doesn't work, try to flush the rewrite rules by the following code:

```
function mytheme_rewrite_flush() {
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
add_action( 'after_switch_theme', 'mytheme_rewrite_flush' );
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules